# PhantomJS: Ensuring that the response object stays alive in server.listen(...)

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I'm using `server.listen(...)` from PhantomJS. I realize that it is largely experimental and that it shouldn't be used in production. I'm using it for a simple screenshot-server that accepts generates screenshots for a URL; it's a toy project that I'm using to play around with PhantomJS. I've noticed an issue with long-running requests in particular, where the `response` object is unavailable. Here are the relevant snippets from my code:

```
var service = server.listen(8080, function (request, response) {

    response.statusCode = 200;

    if (loglevel === level.VERBOSE) {
        log(request);
    } else {
        console.log("Incoming request with querystring:", request.url);
    }

    var params = parseQueryString(request.url);
    if (params[screenshotOptions.ACTION] === action.SCREENSHOT) {
        getScreenshot(params, function (screenshot) {

            response.headers["success"] = screenshot.success; //<-- here is where I get the error that response.headers is unavailable. Execution pretty much stops at that point for that particular request.
            response.headers["message"] = screenshot.message;

            if (screenshot.success) {
                response.write(screenshot.base64);
            } else {
                response.write("<html><body>There were errors!<br /><br />");
                response.write(screenshot.message.replace(/\n/g, "<br />"));
                response.write("</body></html>");
            }

            response.close();
        });
    } else {
        response.write("<html><body><h1>Welcome to the screenshot server!</h1></body></html>")   
        response.close();
    }
});
```

`getScreenshot` is an asynchronous method that uses the `WebPage.open(...)` function to open a webpage; this function is also asynchronous. So what seems to be happening is that when the callback that is passed in as an argument to `getScreenshot` is finally called, it appears that the `response` object has already been deleted. I basically end up with the following error from PhantomJS:

```
Error: cannot access member `headers' of deleted QObject
```

I believe this is because the request times out and so the connection is closed. The documentation mentions calling `response.write("")` at least once to ensure that the connection stays open. I tried calling `response.write("")` at the beginning of `server.listen(...)` and I even tried a pretty hacky solution where I used `setInterval(...)` to perform a `response.write("")` every 500 milliseconds (I even lowered it down to as little as 50). I also made sure to clear the interval once I was done. However, I still seem to get this issue.

Is this something that I'm just going to have to deal with until they make the webserver module more robust? Or is there a way around it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to figure this out. It appears that while loading certain pages with `WebPage.open` (for example `http://fark.com` and `http://cnn.com`) multiple `onLoadFinished` events are fired. This results in the callback in `WebPage.open` being called multiple times. So what happens is that when control comes back to the calling function, I've already closed the response and so the `response` object is no-longer valid. I fixed this by using creating a flag before the `WebPage.open` function is called. Inside the callback, I check the status of the flag to see if I've already encountered a previous `onLoadFinished` event. Once I am with whatever I have to do inside the `WebPage.open` callback, I update the flag to show that I've finished processing. This way spurious (at least in the context of my code) `onLoadFinished` events are no-longer serviced.

Comment: i also changed the server keepalive to false, that seemed to help too-  service = server.listen(port, { keepAlive: false }, function (request, response) {....

Comment: You are awesome. Thanks for breaking down how you solved your problem. Just ran into the same issue.

Comment: Re Chris' comment above - at least as of PhantomJS 1.9.7, [`keepAlive` defaults to `false`](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/1.9.7/src/webserver.cpp#L116-L118).

Answer (score 0):

*(Note that the following refers to PhantomJS 1.9.7 while the OP was likely referring to 1.6.1 or older.)*

In the event that multiple `onLoadFinished` events are being fired, you can use [`page.open()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/open.html) instead of listening for `onLoadFinished` yourself. Using `page.open()` will wrap your handler in a private handler to ensure that your callback is only called once.

From [the source](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/1.9.7/src/modules/webpage.js#L265-L324):

```
definePageSignalHandler(page, handlers, "_onPageOpenFinished", "loadFinished");
page.open = function (url, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4) {
    var thisPage = this;
    if (arguments.length === 1) {
        this.openUrl(url, 'get', this.settings);
        return;
    }
    else if (arguments.length === 2 && typeof arg1 === 'function') {
        this._onPageOpenFinished = function() {
            thisPage._onPageOpenFinished = null;
            arg1.apply(thisPage, arguments);
        }
        this.openUrl(url, 'get', this.settings);
        return;
    }
// ... Truncated for brevity
```

This functionality is exactly the same as the other answer, exposed as part of the official API.